# node_modules directory structure

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I have the follow node_modules and I have some question.
[image]

[image]

1. What's the directory prefixed with underline `_`?
2. How the program that in `.bin` directory generate and when to use them?
3. When I first run `npm install` and install all the package, do they will store in **npm cache**? When I run `npm install` again, what's the operation process of npm?

Answer (score 0):

1 - means nothing particular
2 - they are added during `npm install`, most of the time you don't use it manually
3 - regarding the npm cache, you can obtain [more info here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache)